# Edit/Add Columns in a ListView (eg, add a textbox or button)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there an Edit/Add Columns feature for a ListView, as there is for a GridView? If so, how do you access it?

Just wondering, because I would like to add a columns with a textbox and a button, in a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You may also look at this chart to see which control works best for you.
http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/09/06/comparing-listview-with-gridview-datalist-and-repeater.aspx